# HDMI connection is not detected

Tags: 13.04, intel-graphics, hdmi

I have the Samsung 530U3C ultrabook with Intel HD4000 graphics. I have Ubuntu 13.04 (fresh install).
The laptop is connected to the TV HDMI port, but it isn't detected by the laptop.
The TV shows that it's HDMI port is used.

In Windows everything works flawlessly: detection, image, sound.

I also installed the intel drivers using Intel Linux Graphics Drivers application.

Do you have any idea what can I do next?

Comment: There might be a key on your keyboard to change the laptop display to use the hdmi display

Comment: Yes, there is, but it doesn't do anything

Answer (score 0):

I think that ubuntu 13.04 already comes with intel 4000 drivers... try to Displays menu and try to find the tv, if you can't maybe the hmdi driver isn't set. Have you already tried to contact samsung?

Comment: In Win7 it works, so it isn't a hardware issue. The Display menu shows only the laptop display. Other ideas?